Permanently delete site from Chrome Android address bar
I am trying to delete a site from the address bar in Chrome Android. I have already deleted the site from my history. I have cleared all my cookies.
I have done this that seems to be suggested everywhere. Not sure if I am doing this one correctly since it does not mention Android.
https://osxdaily.com/2021/10/22/how-delete-chrome-url-links-address-bar/


Open the Chrome browser and start typing the URL or link that you wish to remove, for example “myURL.com”
Use the keyboard to navigate to the URL/link you’d like to remove from the pop-up suggestion list
With the link/URL highlighted, use e keystroke to delete that URL/link from the suggestion list

Mac: Shift+FN+Delete
Windows: Shift + Delete
Chromebook: Alt + Shift + Delete




I have tried this one.
https://gadgetmates.com/google-chrome-delete-url-for-website-in-address-bar

The first thing you’ll want to check is to see if there’s a small ‘X’ at the end of the line you’re trying to delete. That’s usually the easiest way to do it and will show up on different device types. Otherwise use these methods.

Not sure what else to try.
